# An apparently weaker criterion for ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

> Is there an example of a ring $R$ (without unity!) together with an additively closed subset $I$ containing $0 \in R$ such that $rx, xr \in I$ whenever $r \in R$ and $x \in I$, but that does **not form** an ideal?

In other words, will being an additive sub-monoid ($0 \in I$ and $I+I=I$) and satisfying $RI \subset I$ and $IR \subset I$ suffice to make $I \subset R$ an ideal?

I was playing around and had accidentally verified this condition instead of the usual subtractive closure in checking that something was an ideal.  In my particular instance it's easy to go back and put in some minus signs, but having gone through my tiny repertoire of standard (counter-)examples, now I'm wondering whether the above actually forces $I$ to be an ideal.  (There had better be no $1 \in R$ since that would immediately invite $-1 \in R$ then $I-I=I$.)

Examples in commutative rings preferred (should there be such a non-ideal), but if one is too difficult to describe then let's say the ideal is two-sided as formulated above.

Comment: Noninteresting example: Let $M$ be a submonoid of an abelian group $(G,+)$, such that $M$ is not a subgroup of $G$, and endow $G$ with the zero multiplication. Concrete example: the subset $\mathbb N$ of $(\mathbb Z,+,\cdot_0)$ satisfy your conditions, yet it is not an ideal.

Comment: @MatemáticosChibchas :  Whoa, I didn't think of that.  (Why does it never cross my mind to set certain things to trivial?)  That is a legit answer, though, so thanks!  If nothing more substantial comes along then I'm happy with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $R\subset\mathbb{Z}[x]$ be the rng of polynomials which have no constant term and let $I\subset R$ be the set of polynomials whose linear coefficient is nonnegative.  Then $I$ satisfies your conditions but is not an ideal (since $x\in I$ but $-x\not\in I$).